# Import huge data to SQL using .net

Tags: c#, xml, import

I have 4 large XML files which needs to be mapped and imported into a SQL database once every month.

I'm Using c# and a console app to do this. My first approach was entity framework which was really slow for 65000 records I had.

There is no issue in deserialization of the data my main issue is adding and updating data in a Unit testable manner within a reasonable time.

Thanks.

Comment: which size your data?

Comment: I suggest you specify your rdbms and substitute `sql` tag with the tag of this rdbms

Answer (score 0):

You can process the `XML` file [parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The bottleneck are the file accesses related to the database operations. Therefore I doubt that parallel processing will help much.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlBulkCopy class contains good facilities for inserting many rows in bulk. If this is still too slow, you can get some benefit from chunking the data and running mutiple bulk copies in parallel with Parallel.ForEach.

For testing, I recommend having the test create a temporary SqlExpress database and pointing your code at that.